# Which XSLT Processor for C++?

Tags: c++, xslt, libxml2, xalan

I started off with Xalan for C++, but that really seemed like overkill for this project. I will have an XML file in memory, there is one stylesheet to run it through... and that's pretty much it.

The input XML and the stylesheet are all in-house and validated for integrity before it gets to my code so I really just wanted the simplest way to do this sort of transformation. I looked at **libxslt**, but it's C-based. The home page referred me to xmlwrapp which I started working with only to find out that this project hasn't been supported for a while.

Do you think xmlwrapp is a good choice for my needs, or would you recommend a different library?

Comment: I used to use [Sablotron](http://freshmeat.net/projects/sablotron/), though I don't know if it meets all your needs.

Comment: The fact that libxml is a C library shouldn't be too much of a problem: what you seem to want to do is exactly what the xsltproc utility already does. Personally, I'd take a look at how that works and just wrap its functionality into a class, borrowing some (most?) of its code.

Comment: I still have a lot to learn in the C-world. You are saying that I can use a C library inside of some C++ code?

I'll give xsltproc a look right now, thanks.

Comment: Yeah, and isn't xsltproc a command-line tool? I'm looking for something I can integrate into my program. My XML data will be in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C libraries integrate well will C++ code. The only issue is if the library itself is compiled as C it will not have C++ style name mangling. This can easily be worked around by ensuring that all the headers have the `extern "C" { ... }` wrappers. Most C libraries will already have this together with the `#ifdef __cplusplus` preprocessor statement which allows total interoperability with C++. Bearing this in mind you should be able to use `libxslt` directly